# Web scraping, separar texto de una columna

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scraping, beautifulsoup

estoy realizando web scraping una una pagina de sismos, en la tabla de sismos aparecen los datos que necesito pero especificamente el dato de **"magnitud"** viene con numeros y texto, lo que necesito es que cuando realice el raspado y me guarde el csv me separe el texto de los numeros y genere una nueva columna

```
Latitud Longitud    Profundidad [Km]    Magnitud    Referencia Geográfica
-32.438 -71.502            26.7           2.5 Ml     25 km al O de La Ligua
-23.835 -67.207            243.2          3.2 Ml     75 km al E de Socaire
```

**EL CODIGO**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame


e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

# Ejemplo de como imprimir todo
# print soup.prettify()

# Obtenemos la tabla

tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

# Obtenemos todas las filas
rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

output_rows = []
for row in rows:
    # obtenemos todas las columns
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    output_row = []
    if len(cells) > 0:
        for cell in cells:
            output_row.append(cell.text)
        output_rows.append(output_row)

dataset = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)

dataset.columns = [
    "Fecha Local",
    "Fecha UTC",
    "Latitud",
    "Longitud",
    "Profundidad [Km]",
    "Magnitud",
    "Referencia Geográfica",
]
dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]] = dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)

dataset_filter = dataset[
    (-27.100 <= dataset["Latitud"])
    & (dataset["Latitud"] <= -21.680)
    & (-72.150 <= dataset["Longitud"])
    & (dataset["Longitud"] <= -66.180)
]

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") #leer archivo data.csv


con = pd.concat([dataset_filter, df]).astype({"Profundidad [Km]":float, "Latitud":float}) # concatenar dataset_filter y df, ademas cambia string a float las columnas Profundidad [Km] y Latitud

con = con.drop_duplicates()

con.to_csv("data.csv",  index=None) # crear csv con archivos concatenados
```

Comment: Por que no pruebas usando expresiones regulares, o incluso codificar tu propia función para hacer eso sin usar regex? Piensa, que reglas sigue lo que quieres separar en dos partes?

Comment: Tal como dice Dante, sí tu columna de análisis es `Magnitud`, puedes tranquilamente aplicarle  `split()` a cada registro de dicha columna sin necesidad de utilizar  `regex`. y tendrías en la primer posición el dato númerico, y en la segunda la escala utilizada

Comment: Prueba poniendo `magnitud=df.iloc[:,3].str.split(' ')` y con eso consigues separar en dos la magnitud

Comment: en que linea deberia ir

Comment: aun no puedo resolver

Comment: pero al volver a realizar el rapado me sigue generando mas columnas, necesito que se mantenga solo las 2 que tienen lo que se separo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues de ...

con = con.drop_duplicates()

Esto debe funcionarte, ten en cuenta que el resultado final tambien contiene la actual columna 'magnitud', en el caso que no la quieras mantener solo tienes que hacerle drop

```
con['magnitud']=con['magnitud'].astype(str)
f =con["magnitud"].str.split(' ', expand=True)
f.columns = ['numeros', 'letras']
con2 = pd.concat([con, f], axis=1)
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo a separar lo que necesitaba, ahora el problema esta en que cada actualización del archivo data.csv se esta generando nuevas columnas ['numeros', 'letras']

Comment: aun no puedo resolver